# Stating well-foundedness in first-order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let's consider the signature of the ordered sets theory as having just two binary relations $=$ and $\leq$ and no functions. Now, consider whether we can express the well-foundedness property as a formula of first-order logic.

What I've come up with is
$$
\lnot \exists x(\exists y(y < x) \land \forall y ((y < x) \rightarrow \exists z (z < y))),
$$
where I also took the liberty to use $x<y$ as a shorthand for $(x \leq y) \land \lnot (x = y)$.

Essentially, this is a negation of the statement that there exists an infinitely decreasing sequence. But I've been hinted that this might not be expressible in first-order logic, so am I right, or did I make a mistake?

Comment: To see that it cannot be stated in FOL, consider an ultrapower of $(\Bbb N,\leq)$ by any non-principal ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$.

Comment: It is not expressible in first-order logic in the language you stated - of course it is expressible in first order logic in ZFC. Another way to see this is that the set of indices of computable well orderings is $\Pi^1_1$ complete, but if there was any sentence in the language of linear orders that characterized well orders, then we would only need to ask whether a particular ordering satisfies that sentence, which is an arithmetical question. Even if we had a theory in the language of orders, asking whether a particular order satisfies that theory cannot lead us to a $\Pi^1_1$ complete set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ ordered in the usual way and to each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ adjoin an element $n'$ such that $n' < n$. More formally, define a partial order on $\mathbb{Z} \times \{0, 1\}$ by $$(n, s) < (m, t) \iff (s = t = 1 \land n < m) \lor (n = m \land s = 0 \land t = 1).$$

This relation satisfies your formula but is not well-founded.

Comment: Yep, it's enough to just break the inner $\forall$, thanks!